# Loading Skeleton before data totally fetched from api in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to Load Skeleton 10 times before data totally fetched from API in react.js with the following code, but the skeleton not loading...

```
const snippetsdata = snippetsData.data;;
const [snippets, setSnippets] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSnippets(snippetsdata);
    setLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
{loading && Array(10).map(()=>{
                                <SnippetsSkeleton />
                            })}
```

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Array(10)` actually your `map` function doesn't iterate over your array items because `Array(10)` creates an array with a length of 10 but without any elements, so the indices `[0]`, `[1]`, ...,`[9]` is not created. Instead of `Array(10).map(...)` you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) , like this:

```
Array.from({length: 10}, (v,i)=> <SnippetsSkeleton key={i}/>)
```

or

```
Array.from(Array(10), (v,i)=> <SnippetsSkeleton key={i}/>)
```

Another solution to solve your problem is using [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Fill), like this:

```
Array(10).fill(undefined).map((v,i)=> <SnippetsSkeleton key={i}/>);
```